# Reset glContext of a pyqt5 widget

Tags: python, qt, opengl, pyqt5, glumpy

i am using glumpy to visualize graphs. 
Glumpy takes care of uploading data to the GPU using openGl. I am using the "pyqt5" backend.

I encounterd some problems using glumpy. If i bind buffers on the gpu frequently, the program starts to run very slow. I deleted the glumpy programs cpu side (python `del`), also i do not keep any reference and gc should take care of it. 
By doing a heap profiling, figured out, that the only reason for the performance loss is not dereferenced memory on the GPU.

Glumpy is using the glContext of QGLWidget. [here](https://github.com/glumpy/glumpy/blob/master/glumpy/app/window/backends/backend_qt5.py)

```
        if context.isValid():
            self._native_window = QtOpenGL.QGLWidget(context)
        else:
            self._native_window = QtOpenGL.QGLWidget(__glformat__)
```

Reload the whole widget does not work for me.

Is there any way to reload/reinstanciate/refresh the glContext so it unbinds all the buffers?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

First of all, the allocated memory on the GPU was not the reason for my performance issues. 
However, glumpy can "free" GPU memory by the build in `GLObject.deactivate()` method. (I had to write the deactivate() method on the label-renderer [agg-glyph-collection](https://github.com/glumpy/glumpy/blob/a0eebb358b65d57cba953659d4d0897f278c7cc6/glumpy/graphics/collections/agg_glyph_collection.py) myself.

Every GLObject has this method and for me the gloo.Program.deactivate() method solved it by setting the size of the binded buffer to 0.

My issues were caused by the `_event_stack` in the [`app.window.event`](https://github.com/glumpy/glumpy/blob/master/glumpy/app/window/event.py) class.
You can modify the `_event.stack` by `attach(event_handler)` and the `remove_handlers(handler)` method. **If you delete an (shader-)program, the event_handlers are not automatically detached.**
It is an event stack, but has also layers (dicts), the `remove_handlers` method will find the first layer (frame) where one of the given handlers is attached and delete all occurrence of any given handler **but only in this layer/frame**.

So for my purpose, the solution was to detach all of my programs separately.

```
    self.program_points.deactivate()
    self.skip_plane_program.deactivate()
    self.axes_program.deactivate()
    self.labels_graph_program.deactivate()
    self.labels_axis_program.deactivate()
    # this is necessary because glumpy breaks symmetry between push and pop on event_stack
    window.remove_handlers(self.program_points['transform'])
    window.remove_handlers(self.axes_program['transform'])
    window.remove_handlers(self.labels_graph_program['transform'])
    window.remove_handlers(self.skip_plane_program['transform'])
    window.remove_handlers(self.labels_axis_program['transform'])
```

This does not work as expected:

```
 window.remove_handlers(self.program_points['transform'], self.axes_program['transform'], self.labels_graph_program['transform'], self.labels_axis_program['transform'])
```